# How can loop through array of JSON Object to find property value that includes user input characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the correct method JavaScript function I can use to loop through an array of JSON data and return the **JSON.KEY** value that includes the user input query

Suppose that we have an array books with these data

```js
const books = [
    { title: 'chemistry', pages: 123 },
    { title: 'chemical abcd', pages: 103 },
    { title: 'anatomy of something ', pages: 423 }
];
```

When a user query is

```
let  query= 'chemi'
```

Then the output should be

```js
filteredBooks = [
    { title: 'chemistry', pages: 123 },
    { title: 'chemical abcd', pages: 103 }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

For this I would use the js [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const filteredBooks = books.filter(book => book.title.includes(query))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of the other questions, using destructuring saves a bit of code:

```
const filteredBooks = books.filter(({title}) => title.includes(query));
```

Answer (score -1):

this method searches all the values of the object if they contain the query. you should make your query lowercase first:

```
query=query.toLowerCase();
filteredBooks = books.filter(book=>Object.values(book).some(value=>value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(query)));
```

if the book object has sub-fields, this is a lazy way to query them:

```
query=query.toLowerCase();
filteredBooks = books.filter(book=>JSON.stringify(Object.values(book)).toLowerCase().includes(query))
```